# In Qt how do QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-16") and codecForName("UTF-32") decide the endianness to use?

Tags: qt, endianness, utf-16, byte-order-mark, utf-32

In the Qt documentation it states that (among others) the following Unicode string encodings are supported:

- UTF-8
- UTF-16
- UTF-16BE
- UTF-16LE
- UTF-32
- UTF-32BE
- UTF-32LE

Due to the three different codecs listed for 2 and 4 octet encoded Unicode, I was wondering: how do the two non-endian codecs ("UTF-16" and "UTF-32") decide which endianness to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the source code in `src/corelibs/codecs/`, it seems Qt uses the byte ordering of the host for UTF-16 and UTF-32.

If you use `QTextCodec` to read an existing Unicode string that has a BOM, and you didn't explicitly ask to ignore the header, the byte ordering detected in the string is used.

- In *qutfcodec_p.h* both `QUtf16Codec::e` and `QUtf32Codec::e` are initialized with the value `DetectEndianness` (an enum).
- In *qutfcodec.cpp*, near the beginning of the functions `convertFromUnicode` and `convertToUnicode` from the classes `QUtf16` and `QUtf32` (used by `QUtf16Codec` and `QUtf32Codec`), you can find the line:

  ```
  endian = (QSysInfo::ByteOrder == QSysInfo::BigEndian) 
      ? BigEndianness : LittleEndianness;
  ```